# ionic 2 check-box value

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am referring [Ionic 2 read checkbox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437889/ionic-2-read-checkbox-value) code in the same manner as described in answer. But I am getting error message in console that:

```
 Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
```

Below is my home.html code:

```
 <form #leadsForm = "ngForm">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Assign to: </ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="saleRep" name="saleRep">
            <ion-option *ngFor="let agency of agencyReps;let i = index;" value="{{agencyRepsIds[i]}}"> {{ agencyReps[i] }}</ion-option>                        
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <button ion-button (click)="assignLeads()" block>Assign</button>

    <ion-list >
        <ion-item *ngFor="let t of leads;">
            <h2 [ngClass]="t.status">{{t.fname}} {{t.lname}} | {{ t.status}}</span></h2>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="{{t}}" [checked]="cbChecked.indexOf('t') >= 0" (change)="updateCheckedOptions(t, $event)" />
            </label>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</form>
```

leads in *ngFor is fetching directly from backend and the leads data is listing perfectly fine.

home.ts is as follows:

```
  export class Leads {
    cbChecked: string[];
    saleRep;

    constructor() { }

    updateCheckedOptions(chBox, event) {
        var cbIdx = this.cbChecked.indexOf(chBox);

        if(event.target.checked) {
          if(cbIdx < 0 ){
               this.cbChecked.push(chBox);
             console.log(chBox);
          }
        } else {
          if(cbIdx >= 0 ){
             this.cbChecked.splice(cbIdx,1);
              console.log(cbIdx);
          }
        }
    }

    assignLeads(){
        console.log('Selected Representative',this.saleRep)
        console.log('CheckBox Value',this.cbChecked);
    }

 }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points:

- `cbChecked: string[] = [];` needs to have an initial value! otherwise its undefined!
- `[checked]="cbChecked.indexOf(t) >= 0"` use `t` here and not `'t'`

Comment: Thank you @mxii.  It works for me. You saved my another half day.

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized `cbChecked` anywhere.

set:

```
 constructor() {
    this.cbChecked=[];
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @suraj for your reply.