# Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined Angular Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, checkbox, undefined

I am currently creating an app using Ionic. I need two checkboxes to see if they are checked or not, so that I can decide where to push the information later.

So I read in the docs that the checkbox framework has an attribute of 'checked' which returns a boolean. First time I tried it, the code looked something like this:

**cc.html**

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Course Start Date</ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="csd"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Course End Date</ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="ced"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
<button ion-button full (click)="AddNewCourse()">
    Add
</button>
```

**cc.ts**

```
csd:any;
ced:any;

AddNewCourse(){
 if(this.csd.checked && this.ced.checked){
    console.log('pushed here');
 }else if(!this.csd.checked && this.ced.checked){
   console.log('push there');
 }
}
```

But I eventually got the error **cannot read property 'checked' of undefined**. So I thought maybe if I initialize the values that would work, so in the constructor:

```
this.csd = false;
this.ced = false;
```

Still gave me the same error. So then after searching for a bit I found out that maybe I should use `[checked]`. But turns out `[(ngModel)]` and `[checked]` do not work together which lead me back to zero.

Finally I thought maybe `ngOnInit()` would do the trick. But unfortunately the same problem persisted.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point, my eyes are getting fuzzy so I'm sure I'm doing something stupid and making something as easy so complex. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: You may use the ngValue property to check the checked or call a function in ngChecked and return a true or false of the model in this way you may use checked and model at the same time

Comment: I am posting a code hold down

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? The code and description you provided makes it seem as though you're using Angular not AngularJS.

Comment: @Narm Yes my mistake, someone did edit that tag. I am using Angular, writing in Typescript.

Comment: Have you checked out this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437889/ionic-2-read-checkbox-value

Answer (score 0):

`csd` and `ced` have only been declared but never initialized. If you want to have a checked property within `csd` and `ced` variables, declare and initialize the property together.

```
csd: any = {checked: false}
ced: any = {checked: false}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Name: <input ng-model="name">
{{checkFn()}}
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="value" ng-checked="checkFn()">
</div>


<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "John Doe";
    $scope.value =true;
    $scope.checkFn= function(){
    return $scope.value ? $scope.value :false;
}
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code example you provided is AngularJs code, this does not help answer the OP at all.